# OCL 2.0 constraint to check if a Key-Value pair is present in the Hashtable

Tags: uml, ocl

How to write a OCL constraint to check if a particular Key-Value pair is always present in a HashTable using iterate feature in OCL? I am a beginner in OCL. Any hints or example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Unique operator for collections. It may be a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Comment: If you are interested in describing such constraint with `iterate`, the OCL specification already includes formal definitions for the collection operations.